# Magic not working in Jupyter Notebook - Trying to run SQLite in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently trying to run SQL in Jupyter Notebook but seem to be having an issue with the magic commands.

When I run my script in the integrated Jupyter Notebook environment on DataQuest I have no issues but as soon as I try to run it in my own browser the "%" turns black and I get errors. I am getting the same problem when I try to run it from the Jupyter extension in VS Code.

[What I think is the problem - Magic not changing colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXmDP.png)

[Image of Functioning code in DataQuest integrated Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a8lq.png)

[Code when I try to open it my own Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MvOe.png)

When I try to run my code in my own Notebook I get the following error:

```
Environment variable $DATABASE_URL not set, and no connect string given.
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

My only other thought is that maybe I'm missing a package? I used miniconda for my initial install package vs anaconda. I have ipython and ipython-sql. Maybe there is a path issue? I'm really new so my troubleshooting abilities aren't the best.

SOLUTION?: Installing `jupysql` resolved the issue. Others were able to run my code without jupysql and using the same environment that I had. I'm not sure why jupysql was necessary on my machine but it works now.

Comment: Is the kernel you are using in your Jupyter Notebook the typical ipykernel and not pyodide based? I only ask because it seems like [this](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-lab-not-executing-python-code/20998?u=fomightez)? Was your kernel ever showing ready before you tried to run your code in the top portion of your image? I see the asterisk so it is certainly thinking it is a code cell but you aren't sharing the before state. Did you give it a few seconds before entering the code and running to try and color the code by syntax highlighting?

Comment: @Wayne I am using the regular ipykernel (Python 3). I took your suggestion and gave the kernel some time and ran some simple commands to ensure it was working. If you notice, it recognizes the magic for %sql but it doesn't seem to change color for %%capture or %load_ext. I'll update my post with some more information. Maybe the issue isn't the magic (I'm just making an assumption based on the lack of color change on the %)

Comment: The syntax highlighting not working is a common bug that does happen. Sometimes though the code still works at least. Weird yours isn't. Is it only with those you mention in your last comment that the syntax highligting gets messed up?

Comment: @Wayne I learned about the bug issue you mentioned and that seems to be the case for me (they gray out but work). I ran across another thread that mentioned jupysql. I installed that and everything seems to work now. What I'm still perplexed about is other people where able to run my code without needing jupysql. -Alex

Comment: I would at least add that stuff about `jupysql` as an edit to your own post or post an answer because the is important. As to why others were able to use it without it, it's hard to say. Were they using old tech and had installed it long ago or set it up to work with SQL so long ago, they didn't know. Maybe it was included in older distributions? Importantly you know the symptom when you don't have it on the new tech and should be able to help.